# Regression fit error in Apache Spark regression algorithm

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, regression

I work on regression on Apache Spark. And I get everytime same error. I can't solve it. 
model = LinearRegression(featuresCol = 'features', labelCol='label').fit(df)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-3156cdf2ca47> in <module>
----> 1 model = lr.fit(df)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 295         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    296         model = self._create_model(java_model)
    297         return self._copyValues(model)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\ml\wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    290         """
    291         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 292         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    293 
    294     def _fit(self, dataset):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o762.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 66.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 66.0 (TID 133, localhost, executor driver): scala.MatchError: [null,1.0,[34.0,147.0,249.0,2006.0,7.0,30.0,38.0,2.0]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.$anonfun$train$2(LinearRegression.scala:325)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:217)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate$(TraversableOnce.scala:217)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$3(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$5(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:274)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1098)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$1(RDD.scala:1161)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1137)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.optim.WeightedLeastSquares.fit(WeightedLeastSquares.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.$anonfun$train$1(LinearRegression.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:183)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: [null,1.0,[34.0,147.0,249.0,2006.0,7.0,30.0,38.0,2.0]] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.$anonfun$train$2(LinearRegression.scala:325)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:160)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:158)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate(TraversableOnce.scala:217)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.aggregate$(TraversableOnce.scala:217)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.aggregate(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$3(RDD.scala:1145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$treeAggregate$5(RDD.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

What is the reason? df is dataframe. How can I solve it? I tried it in my computer and databricks, the result is same. My dataframe is features=[8 numbers], label= one number like [2.0,92.0,1.0,2002.0,9.0,37.0,2.0,2.0] and  99.4